# Q: Twilio Day of week decision

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-functions

On Twilio I have a very simple solution to play an audio file to an incoming call.
I want to configure such that it will play a different Mp3 dependant on the day of week.
e.g. Mon-Friday = first mp3 file
Sat-Sun = second mp3 file

Currently I have to change on a friday evening

I am not a coder so struggling

Current Function below

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.say(
        { voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB' },
        'Welcome to xxxx.');
    twiml.play("url of mp3 file");
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getDay()` to get an index (a number between 0 and 6) representing the day of the week. For example 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday and so on until 6 for Saturday.

**getDay() docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

As such code for your function would become:

```js
const date = new Date();

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.say({ voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB' }, 'Welcome to xxxx.');

    switch (date.getDay()) {
        case 0:
        case 6:
            // Sunday and Saturday
            twiml.play("url of second mp3 file");
            break;
        default:
            // Monday to Friday
            twiml.play("url of first mp3 file");
    }

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

The above code would work with times in UTC if run with Twilio Functions' runtime.

---

If you want to make this work for another timezone, for example Los Angeles, then you'll want to use the `moment-timezone` module.

The module needs to be added in the "Configuration/Dependencies" section of Twilio Functions where you "import NPM modules into your application" (https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure).

The code for the function would then be:

```js
let moment = require("moment-timezone");
const date = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.say({ voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB' }, 'Welcome to xxxx.');

    switch (date.day()) {
        case 0:
        case 6:
            // Sunday and Saturday
            twiml.play("url of second mp3 file");
            break;
        default:
            // Monday to Friday
            twiml.play("url of first mp3 file");
    }

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```